# apply ltac to subexpression of a goal

Tags: coq, ltac

Here is a short example of what I am trying to do.

Let's say I have a relation

```
Inductive divisible: nat -> nat -> Type := 
| one : forall n, divisible n 1.
..etc...
```

I have also the following ltac
`Ltac simplify := autorewrite with blah`

I would like to define a ltac which does simplify to only the first term in a 'divisible' goal. Something like

```
Ltac simplify_fst :=
  match goal with |- (divisible ?N ?M) =>
autorewrite with subst1 in N
  end.
```

When I try out the above in the following,

```
Lemma silly: forall n m, divisible (n + m) 1.
  intros. simplify_fst.
```

I get a

```
Error:
Ltac call to "simplify_fst" failed.
Ltac variable N is bound to n + m which cannot be
coerced to a variable.
```

Can applying ltacs (even simple ones involving only autounfold and autorewrite) be restricted to a subexpression of the goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `remember` may be useful:

```
Ltac simplify_fst :=
  match goal with |- (divisible ?N ?M) =>
    let x := fresh "x" in
    let Hx := fresh "Hx" in
    remember N as x eqn:Hx;
    autorewrite with subst1 in Hx;
    subst x
  end.
```